# C++ matrix multiplication with multithreads and semaphore

Tags: c++, multithreading, semaphore

I have written a program that does a multiplication of two matrices. When I execute it, it works sometimes, sometimes it does not work and sometimes half of the answers are right. I think there is a problem in the usage of thread and semaphore together.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

//NOTE: THIS CODE NEEDS C++11 COMPILER TO COMPILE.

using namespace std;
int const size = 4;
mutex mtx[size][size];
thread myThread[size];


void MatrixMultiplication(int const * const * matrixA, int const * const * matrixB,int** matrixC, int row, int col, int i){
    mtx[row][col].lock();
    matrixC[row][col] += matrixA[row][i]*matrixB[i][col];
    mtx[row][col].unlock();
}

int main()
{
    int** matrixA;
    int** matrixB;
    int** matrixC;

    matrixA = new int*[size];
    matrixB = new int*[size];
    matrixC = new int*[size];

    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        matrixA[i] = new int[size];
        matrixB[i] = new int[size];
        matrixC[i] = new int[size];
    }

    //WE ARE INITIALIZING MATRICES.
    int count = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<size; j++){
            matrixA[i][j] = count;
            matrixB[i][j] = count;
            count++;
        }
    }


    for(int row=0; row<size; row++){
        for(int col=0; col<size;col++){
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
                myThread[i] = thread(MatrixMultiplication, matrixA, matrixB, matrixC, row, col, i);
                myThread[i].join();
            }
        }
    }


    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<size; j++){
            cout<<matrixC[i][j]<<"  ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you executing a thread as a *synchronous* operation in your for-loop? Do you realize that is essentially nothing more than invoking `MatrixMultiplication` directly, but doing so with the extra baggage of a thread startup/shutdown?

Comment: @WhozCraig: Because code runs faster when it has its own thread :-) (okay, to make sure everyone understands, I am in agreement with WhozCraig!)

Comment: No, code runs just as fast. What makes a concurrent program faster is that is has several threads at a time. Which are all performing an operation. Since std::thread::join waits for a thread to finish, creating a thread and calling join right away, will not give you any performance at all. As the main thread is doing nothing, whilst the other threads does the calculation.

Comment: Yes, it indeed looks like homework. Does the code work when you do not create the thread and do the function call directly. And where excatly are you using a semaphore?

Comment: so my usage of thread.join() is wrong?

Comment: I think you should move the call to `join` outside of the loops, in accordance with what @laurisvr said.

Comment: yes my code works fine when i call directly method. the problem is that; when i add [cout<<"asdasd";] inside the loop, it works fine. but when i erase the cout statement it does not work.

Comment: i cant move the join statement outside because i have 16 mutex and only 4 threads :(

Comment: @AnılA your usage of `join()` is wrong, and honestly your usage of *mutexes* isn't needed either. Consider this: Matrix AxB multiplied against another matrix BxC resulting in a matrix AxC has a *known* number of rows and columns to multiply. *Each can be done independently of the others*. Just divide that workload by the number of threads you want to use, then start the threads telling each where to start and how much to do, No locking should be required *at all*.

Comment: yes i know i can do it with lots of different ways but it is asked in this way. i have to use threads and semaphore like that. when i have 4x4 matrix i use a semaphore for each block (means 16 semaphore). and in each block one thread makes one summation. because matrix 4x4, in each block there are 4 summation operations (means 4 thread)

Comment: @laurisvr: *Sigh*, after I go out of my way to point out my sarcasm...

Comment: okay i add second loop inside the second loop and it works :) thanks guys, the problem was usage of join

Comment: @jxh Sorry didn't read properly, I thought you were the OP. In which it would have been sensible:)

Answer (score 1):

There are two things going wrong here as far as i can see.

```
   for(int row=0; row<size; row++){
        for(int col=0; col<size;col++){
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
                myThread[i] = thread(MatrixMultiplication, matrixA, matrixB, matrixC, row, col, i);
                myThread[i].join();
            }
        }
    }
```

Should be

```
   for(int row=0; row<size; row++){
        for(int col=0; col<size;col++){
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
                myThread[i] = thread(MatrixMultiplication, matrixA, matrixB, matrixC, row, col, i);
            }
        }
    }

for(int row=0; row<size; row++){
   for(int col=0; col<size;col++){
      for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
         myThread[i].join();
      }
   }
}
```

This way you first create a bunch of calculations. And then do the actual calculations. However this still is not the way you should approach this. A thread should have a reasonable amount of work.

So before you go ahead and do that, allow me to explain about threading a little bit. A thread does different work *at the same time*. Since it is doing it at the same time, you can never let a thread access data that might be written to by another thread. Otherwise you might end up with data that's half written to( a so called race condition).

Therefore an `std::thread()` call will always copy all the arguments it is given. Even if it's a pointer. What you can do is let each thread do the calculations for each column on a separate thread. However, in order to do that I would recommend creating a `column` struct or class. And passing to the thread by `std::ref`. Passing with `std::ref` will prevent the data from being copied.